# Is it possible to display local variables in laravel error page

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel, laravel-4, whoops

In laravel 4, the debug error pages is very useful. It uses **whoops library**. I am wondering, is it possible to get values of local variables in the error pages? I mean It could display the arguments and the other local variables (by var_dump) for every frame. If it does it would be very useful.

Comment: This package: https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler is very useful to inspect all the vars - enable it on the development environment ;)

Comment: [Related issue](https://github.com/filp/whoops/issues/97).